# Overload lombok setter

Tags: java, lombok

We can use lombok to generate setter like this:

```
@Data                    //or @Setter
public class Test {  
    int a;
}
```

Say for instance I also want an overloaded setter that would take a String:

```
public void setA(String aStr){
    //parseInt and set 'a'
}
```

But when I add this overloaded method, lombok thinks that I have manually added a setter and so it chooses not to add one itself.

Apparently it looks only at the method name and not the parameters.

Is there a way I can force it to add the normal (that takes an `int` as parameter) setter?
Or the only way is to add that normal setter myself (using IDE setter generator of course)? I have a lot of fields and a lot of classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the `@Tolerate` annotation on my overloaded method solved the issue.

[Documentation](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/experimental/Tolerate.html):

> Put on any method or constructor to make lombok pretend it doesn't
>   exist, i.e., to generate a method which would otherwise be skipped due
>   to possible conflicts.

It has been experimental though, since 2014.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that `"No method is generated if any method already exists with the same name (case insensitive) and same parameter count."`.

This is the case that you've described. Instead, you should define an additional custom setter method with a new name like

> setAFromString(String aStr)

Comment: To add on to this. Generally speaking data classes are used as completely or almost completely empty classes ONLY holding data.`In other words, @Data generates all the boilerplate that is normally associated with simple POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) and beans`. I'd say that you're better off adding any logic for data conversion (if necessary) somewhere else. But people have different opinions on the matter.

Comment: you can use @Tolerate, https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/experimental/Tolerate.html

Comment: @martijnp yes, I always have to think what's the best way to do that. In this case I'm doing it within the pojo itself because it's just a String->int conversion and nothing huge. For _huge_ things I use classes, like Spring converters. But I'm not sure what the best way is, as you said, different people have different opinions.

Comment: @GvSharma I don't usually recommend features from experimental since they are subject of change / deletion. For big, enterprise projects, I am only using features from the stable version.